# How to specify AND, OR with dynamic query

Tags: 8, database

I’m trying to create a dynamic query, the query logic conditions needed are: AND, and OR.

The main query will include two sub queries.

The ConditionInterface::condition documentation states that:

> If called with 1 parameter, it should be a ConditionInterface that in
>   itself forms a valid where clause. Use e.g. to build clauses with
>   nested AND's and OR's.

I cannot find the example to build clauses with nested AND’s and OR’s so I’ve done some digging through the ConditionInterface API Reference (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21ConditionInterface.php/interface/ConditionInterface/8.6.x)

I found a function conditionGroupFactory (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21ConditionInterface.php/function/ConditionInterface%3A%3AconditionGroupFactory/8.6.x)

The conditionGroupFactory function appears to be what I need, however I cannot find any implementation examples.

Could someone please explain the implementation of this function.

```
$result = $connection->select('inventory', 'inv');
$result->fields('inv', ['part_number']);
$result->condition('inv.visable', 1);
$result->conditionGroupFactory('AND')->condition('inv.part_number', $queryOne, 'IN');
$result->conditionGroupFactory('OR')->condition('inv.part_number', $queryTwo, 'IN');
```

Note: `$queryOne, $queryTwo;` Are of type SelectInterface.

My Objective SQL Statement:

```
SELECT inv.part_number
 FROM inventory AS inv
 WHERE inv.visable = 1
 AND (inv.part_number IN (SUBQUERY_1)
 OR  inv.part_number IN (SUBQUERY_2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the same structure of your table  but i test it with the following statement it works:

```
SELECT *
 FROM `node__body` AS n_b
 WHERE n_b.`deleted` = 0
 AND (
 n_b.`revision_id` IN (32,6,17)
 OR  n_b.`langcode` IN ('fr')
 );
```

here is the code snippet for your case:

```
  $query = $connection->select('inventory', 'inv')
    ->fields('inv', ['part_number'])
    ->condition('inv.visable', '1', '=');
  //- Set Or Query group
  $group = $query
    ->orConditionGroup()
    ->condition('inv.part_number', [SUBQUERY_1], 'IN')
    ->condition('inv.part_number', [SUBQUERY_2], 'IN');
  //- Add Or group 
  $query->condition($group);
  $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```